# Visit something or visit to something

Tags: usage

In the following sentence

> Mr. Modi, who arrived in Russia on a two-day visit, during which he will also attend the Eastern Economic Forum (EEF), is the first Indian Prime Minister to **visit to** the Russian Far East region.

[Link](https://www.thehindu.com/news/international/india-russia-inks-proposal-on-developing-chennai-vladivostok-sea-route/article29331175.ece?homepage=true)

I think instead of **visit to** only **visit** should be used, because visit something is the correct construction

Answer (score 1):

I would say you're right, a better way to word the sentence is:

> Mr. Modi is the first Indian Prime Minister to visit <strike>to</strike> the Russian Far East region.

Perhaps the journalist was conflating that wording with this one, which is also quite valid and often used:

> Mr. Modi is the first Indian Prime Minister to **make a** visit to the Russian Far East region.

In that sentence, the word *to* after *visit* would be required.